# How to set will last will message in Moscapsule (swift mqtt library)?

Tags: ios, swift, mqtt

I am using moscapsule in my project for chatting purpose, I want to know how one can set Last will message in it, so that whenever a user goes offline or exits the app without disconnecting the topic other users and brokers can know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last will message works only when the user gets disconnected abruptly

```
  var a:NSString = "I:Have:Left:The:Chat"
        var b: NSData = a.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    var tempMqttWillOps:MQTTWillOpts = MQTTWillOpts(topic: "foo", payload: b, qos: 2, retain: true)
    mqttConfig.mqttWillOpts = tempMqttWillOps
```